# Why doesn't array.push() mutate the array?

Tags: javascript, mutation

Here is the question:

> Remove all falsy values from an array.
>
> Falsy values in JavaScript are false, null, 0, "", undefined, and NaN.
>
> Hint: Try converting each value to a Boolean.

Here is my code:

```js
function bouncer(arr) {
  let arr2 =[];
  let items = arr.map((item)=>{
    if(item == false){
      arr2.push(item);
    }
    return arr;
  })
  return items;
}

console.log(bouncer([7, "ate", "", false, 9]));
```

I also tried another method:

```js
function bouncer(arr) {
  let arr2 =[];
  for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    if(arr[i] == false){
      arr2.push(arr[i]);
    }
  }
  return arr;
}


console.log(bouncer([7, "ate", "", false, 9]));
```

I was at the very least expecting this to push the item that is called false out into the other array. Why does the mutation not occur in either of these instances?

Comment: `arr2.push` mutates `arr2`, not `arr`...

Comment: You should read about `Array#filter` ;)

Answer (score 2):

It does, you just **never inspect** `arr2`.

Calling `push` on `arr2` won't mutate `arr` though. That's a different array.

```js
function bouncer(arr) {
  let arr2 =[];
  for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    if(arr[i] == false){
      arr2.push(arr[i]);
    }
  }
  console.log({ arr, arr2 });
}


bouncer([7, "ate", "", false, 9]);
```

Comment: Ok I see, so it doesn't mutate the original

Answer (score 0):

See [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62771417/295783) for explanation.

Here is what I think you wanted - remove all falsy values from array

```js
const bouncer = arr => arr.filter(item => item);

console.log(bouncer([7, "ate", "", false, 9]));
```

Mutate:

```js
const bouncer = arr => {
  arr = arr.filter(item => item)
  return arr; // does NOT mutate the original
};

let arr = [7, "ate", "", false, 9]
console.log(bouncer(arr));
console.log(arr); // not mutated
arr = bouncer(arr); // replace
console.log(arr)
```

Answer (score -3):

Solution inspired by people aboves comments:

```js
function bouncer(arr) {
  let arr2 =[];

  let items = arr.filter((item)=>{
    let a = Boolean(item);
    return a == true;
  })
  return items;
}

console.log(bouncer([7, "ate", "", false, 9]));
```